# Postgres SQL - audit check compare

Tags: postgresql

I have a table TEST.   I am concerned about two columns - NODE and DESCRIPTION - in that table.  There are exactly two records for each DESCRIPTION.  The NODE should be the same value for each of these two. I would like to output each record where DESCRIPTION has different NODE.

This is an audit check.  In ideal, there is no OUTPUT.   But when DESCRIPTION has two different nodes, would like to output.

Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to aggregate by `description` and `node`, to count matching rows and to display them if there are not just two

```
SELECT description, node, count(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY description, node
HAVING count(*) <> 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is finding different node,description combinations so *count() ... group*  will not solve it as that identifies only the number of rows where they **are** the same. Try:

```
select distinct t1.description, t1.node, t2.node
   from test t1
   join test t2
     on (t1.description = t2.description and
         t1.node != t2.node)
  where t1.node < t2.node
  order by description, t1.node;
```